# How to refresh a specific frame in CEFSharp

Tags: winforms, frame, cefsharp

I have a Winforms Application using .NET 4.7.2 and CEFSharp 84.4.10.

I have a website loaded into the CEF browser that has a frameset and I want to have a menu item in the context menu that will reload a specific frame.

I have the menu item happening and in the event handler I tried the following two approaches but they both reload the entire browser, not just the frame.

How can I reload just the frame?

Thank you for your time.

```
    bool IContextMenuHandler.OnContextMenuCommand(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, CefMenuCommand commandId, CefEventFlags eventFlags)
    {
        switch ((int)commandId)
        {
            ...

            case RefreshContentFrame:
                frame.Browser.Reload(true);
                break;
            ...
        }

        return false;
    }
```

and

```
    bool IContextMenuHandler.OnContextMenuCommand(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IContextMenuParams parameters, CefMenuCommand commandId, CefEventFlags eventFlags)
    {
        switch ((int)commandId)
        {
            ...

            case RefreshContentFrame:
                var myFrame = browser.GetFrame("MyFrame");
                if (myFrame != null)
                {
                    myFrame.Browser.Reload(true);
                }
                break;
            ...
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: The CEF API doesn't support reloading of a single frame currently (remembering that CefSharp is just one of many chromium embedded framework wrappers). You can execute JavaScript for a specific frame,  try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Comment: @amaitland thanks for clarifying this.  I used JS no problems.

Comment: Great. Looking at the source and it looks like support could be added, https://github.com/chromiumembedded/cef/blob/0dfefe391c317b43e92733a416640b9ba6321aa5/libcef/renderer/browser_impl.cc#L93 there's a feature  request  forum at https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewforum.php?f=7&sid=befbec74d6f02c56066bab915cc841b9 if you are so inclined.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @amaitland for clarifying that reloading a single frame is not currently supported.  I went with the solution doing it via JS API.